# Why is passing by reference lambda accepted pointer pointing to a different address?

Tags: c++

Why is passing by reference lambda accepted pointer pointing to a different address?

```
Bootstrap* APIServer::bs = nullptr;

std::thread* APIServer::start_srv(Bootstrap* bootstrap) {

  auto sv_th = new std::thread([&] {
    APIServer::bs = bootstrap;  // checked here, pointer bootstrap already differ than in the caller.
    Environment::init();
  });

  return sv_th;
}

Bootstrap* bootstrap = new Bootstrap();  // 0x5555556a3c50
// When I debug I see that inside the thread lambda the bootstrap pointer's value is 0x5555556835c0
```

When I call APIServer::start_srv(bootstrap); When I debug I see that inside the thread lambda the bootstrap pointer's value is 0x5555556835c0, but if I change the signature to `[=]{}`, the problem's gone, why?

Comment: The lambda is capturing a reference to a local variable that is out of scope by the time the thread reads it. Undefined Behavior. Capturing the variable by value does not suffer from that problem.

Comment: You mean if I use bootstrap somewhere in the function `start_srv` so that it doesn't go out of scope, then using a passing by ref instead should be OK?

Comment: The parameter `bootstrap` in `start_srv()` is a different variable than the `bootstrap` that you are passing into `start_srv()`. You are capturing the former, but it seems you want to capture the latter instead. Which you can't do in this code. But capture by value should work fine.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you pointed it out accurately, If I add a simple use of `bootstrap parameter` before the line `new thread` it preserved the value. and it seems run fine, I tried it out for several times, so in the original code in my question it looks like the parameter is never used except for the thread lambda.

Comment: In general when capturing data to pass to another thread capture by value unless by design you know that something is going to outlive the livetime of the thread then you can capture by reference. Also capturing a std::shared_ptr (by value) to data has its uses when you cannot guarantee the lifetime of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lambda is capturing by reference, inside the lambda, the name `bootstrap` refers to the function parameter `bootstrap` of the outer function `APIServer::start_srv`, which is a local variable. The lambda stores the address to this local variable and when the lambda is passed by value to the constructor of `std::thread`, the address is also copied along with it. In the new thread, the address is refering to a variable which is not within its lifetime, which results in undefined behavior and what you see is an exhibition of it.

If the lambda is capturing by value, the value of the local variable `bootstrap` is stored in the lambda and then later copied to the new thread along with the lambda itself. Since it is properly copied to the new thread, you can safely access the value inside the lambda, and the value is just the same as the original argument to the `APIServer::start_srv` call.

The fact that the parameter is a pointer is irrelavent to the issue, you can have the same issue with a simple `int`.

If we want to say more than just standardese, it is due to the fact that each thread has its own stack, and passing a stack address to a different thread and then accessing the memory associated with it in the new thread does not really make sense.